# Creating a simple Chat Client/Server

Tags: java

i was trying creating Client/server Chat in console "not gui" , in gui case i can add action listener to the JTextField and every time that user hit enter the data will be send it to the client and vise versa , in console java application how can i do that ?? i mean how could i listen to the console (or) should i listen to the BufferReader so if it full then read the Buffer ???

Comment: If its chat app then why it doesn't have any ui?

Comment: @Harry Joy I see nothing wrong with making a chat app for a console to learn.

Comment: @Robert: Normally all chat app have ui.

Comment: @Harry Joy Of course do all chat apps have UIs, but not all have GUIs ;)

Comment: is there an problem with console :) , i dont like GUI

Answer (score 0):

You can do smth like :

```
String StrRead() {
    byte[] enter = new byte[256];
    int num = 0;
    String str = new String();
    try {    
        num = System.in.read(enter);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    str = new String(enter,0,num);
    return str.trim();
}
```

and then just call String s = StrRead();